# Dynamically getting user object using discord php

Tags: php, discord

How do you dynamically find a user object using discords api in php? Down below is some working code to find a user object in node js but I cant seem to find much documentation about the php version and am a little stuck.I just need that code but basically in php.

NODEJS CODE

```
const GUILD_ID = 'HIDDEN'; //edit serverid 
const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get(GUILD_ID);
const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.id === savedmemberidvariablehere);
```

Comment: https://www.restcord.com/User/Get%20User/